# Nivo Slider pushing image down

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

I'm trying to use the nivo slider. I had it originaly set to "fold" the trasnistions. It worked fine. I changed it to "fade" and now when the image fades to the next, it appears pushed down. Anyone had this issue before? Here is the jQuery and css.

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed:500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime:5000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide:4, // Set starting Slide (0 index)

/Nevo Slider/

slider {

position:relative;
width:900px;
height:250px;
background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

slider img {

position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}

slider a {

border:0;
display:block;
} /End of Nevo Slider/
```

Here is a link
http://kerrydean.ca/Grey%20River/greyRiverTemplate2.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and I found several tips across the web but none of them worked for me.  Here is the CSS rule that fixed the problem for me:

```
div.nivo-slice { position:absolute; z-index: 99; top:0 }
```

I added the top:0 and it shifted the images into place.  Also, this image shifting issue seems to only happen when using the 'fade' feature.

Comment: Nice this helped me fix an ie8 issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it solved when I added the theme-default class to the div#slider

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
```

and of course loaded the default.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `.nivoSlider` class to your #slider id housing the images, also, you're including jQuery twice.

Comment: Thanks,But still not working. I figure its gotta be something in the css

Comment: adding this to the css worked..nivo-controlNav {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:9;
width:100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Is it in WordPress? If so, you will need to hide the `<p>` tags that get added automatically. Add this CSS and this should do the trick (at least it worked for me):

```
.nivoSlider p { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need remove all object tag wrapped image on your slide.

Example: from

```
<ul id="slider">
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<div id="slider">
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
</div>
```